# Why the @Qualifier annotation not work in spring boot 1.5.2,but work in spring boot 1.2.7

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my project, I use `@Qualifier` to get bean object with same class.
In spring boot 1.2.7 the code:

In class a:

```
@Component
public class DeamonTaskJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private QuartzTriggerService quartzTriggerService;

    @Autowired
    private QuartzService quartzService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    }

    @Bean(name = "deamonJob")
    public JobDetailFactoryBean deamonJob() throws Exception{
        return QuartzConfig.createJobDetail(this.getClass(),TRIGGER_JOB);
    }

    @Bean(name = "deamon")
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean deamonJobTrigger(@Qualifier("deamonJob") JobDetail jobDetail) throws Exception {
        return QuartzConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail,TRIGGER_JOB);
    }
}
```

In class b:

```
@Component
public class TestTaskJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private TestTaskService testTaskService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        logger.info("test job start");
        Boolean isSuccess = testTaskService.testService();
        logger.info("test job start");
    }

    @Bean(name = "testJob")
    public JobDetailFactoryBean deamonJob() throws Exception{
        return QuartzConfig.createJobDetail(this.getClass(),TRIGGER_JOB);
    }

    @Bean(name = "test")
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean deamonJobTrigger(@Qualifier("testJob") JobDetail jobDetail) throws Exception {
        return QuartzConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail,TRIGGER_JOB);
    }
}
```

It works well.

But I merge these code to spring boot 1.5.2, it not work. the error is:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.quartz.JobDetail] found for dependency [org.quartz.JobDetail]: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(val‌​ue=testJob)}
```

When I comment the code `@Bean(name = "deamonJob")` out in class a, it works well.

Then I revert the code and I add annotation `@Primary` to testJob method in class b, it works. when I add new bean like below, it not work again with same error.

Then I use another method to use the bean with `ApplicationContext` annotation,the code like this:

```
@Bean(name = "testJob")
@Primary
public JobDetailFactoryBean testJob() throws Exception{
    return QuartzConfig.createJobDetail(this.getClass(),TRIGGER_JOB);
}

@Bean(name = "test")
public CronTriggerFactoryBean testTrigger() throws Exception {
    JobDetail integralBlackListJobDetail = (JobDetail)appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean("testJob");
    return QuartzConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail,TRIGGER_JOB);
}
```

it works well.

Could anybody tell me why? thank you.

Comment: paste more lines of the error you get.

Comment: If anywhere else in the codebase any class requests a JobDetail or JobDetailFactoryBean without giving @Qualifier, spring will be confused.

Comment: yes, i kown it is basic. i have updated my code, see the issue again. thank you @tkruse,the error is No qualifying bean of type [org.quartz.JobDetail] found for dependency [org.quartz.JobDetail]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=testJob)}

Comment: Still not enough error log to be sure. You should post where exactly Spring cannot inject, it should be in the error message. Also there might be more 'caused by' error messages or warning that would also help. Usually in Spring all the information required is in the logs, but you need to post them for others to help.

Comment: I have the same problem (Spring Boot 1.5.X + Quartz 2.2.3). Any progress?